# Add get route to table using Form or HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I have a `class="table table-hover"` table and am trying to make it clickable. The table consists of user ID, Name and other attributes. My first attempt was to make the whole row clickable but it took time and I failed to do so. Now I decided to make the user ID clickable by this code :

```
@foreach($user as $users)

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> {{link_to('home', $title = $users->id)}} </td>
                <td>{{$users->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$users->phone}}</td>
                <td>{{$users->city}}</td>
                <td>{{$users->street}}</td>
                <td>{{$users->national_id}}</td>
                @endforeach
```

And this is my route

```
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'],function () {
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::Resource('/user', 'UserController');
 });


Route::get('/admin', 'HomeController@adminIndex');
```

My question is how can I make the id clickable where it should be a GET method to the SHOW function (`public function show($id)`). Meaning `user/1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a **td** that contains an anchor in it like:

```
<td><a href="{{ url('/showdetails').'/'.$users->id }}"></a></td>
```

here showdetails is defined in the route and call a method of some controller like:

```
function showDetails(Request $request)  // $request will return $users->id
{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Sorry I tried what you told me but the url returns `http://localhost:8000/user4` instead of `http://localhost:8000/user/4` @Mayank Pandeyz

Comment: Please check updated answer in which I have make a slight change href="{{ url('/showdetails').'/'.$users->id }}"